# How to let MAKEFILE retain the backslash sequences within a string when used in a make rule?

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile, gnu

This is my first question on Stackoverflow so forgive me if I ask anything ridiculous :D. 
**Problem:**
Suppose I want to compile a program that is in the directory "my dir/" with a space in it. Say the pathname of the program is "my dir/test.c".
Here is the sample makefile that I was trying out:

```
CC = gcc
DIR = my\ dir
$(DIR)/test.out: $(DIR)/test.c
#   $(CC) $< -o $@
    $(CC) $(DIR)/test.c -o $(DIR)/test.out
```

As you can see that in the last line(line-5) I have written the pathnames of the source and the output files directly as written in the prerequisite and the target, respectively. Doing this works fine because it yields the command:
**gcc my\ dir/test.c -o my\ dir/test.out**
which a syntactically correct way of passing filenames(with spaces) to *gcc* or any other shell command.

The second last line(line-4) is where the problem is(commented line). I've used automatic variables $@ (Target) and $< (First and the only Prerequisite) to produce the filename arguments for *gcc* which I expected to be
**my\ dir/test.out** and **my\ dir/test.c**, respectively. But here, for some reason, the produced filenames are **my dir/test.out** and **my dir/test.c** and hence the yielded command is:
 **gcc my dir/test.c -o my dir/test.out**
Now here, gcc considers **my** and **dir/test.c** as different two different input filenames and the command generates errors.
Here is a screenshot of the generated error output when I uncomment line-4 and comment line-5 of the above Makefile:
[image: make output]

**My Question:**
Is there any way to retain those backslashes even by using automatic variables the way I did? Or is there any alternative that will achieve the same goal as using automatic variables and also solve my problem? Because flexibility is important here.

Thanks in advance for your help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double or single quotes for the automatic variables.

Use single quotes, if you want to avoid shell expansion of the values referenced by the automatic variables:

```
$(DIR)/test.out: $(DIR)/test.c
    $(CC) '$<' -o '$@'
```

Double quotes allow shell expansion. For example, if there was a dollar sign in `DIR`:

```
DIR := $$my\ dir
```

then `"$@"` would expand to `"$my dir"`, and the shell would interpret `$my` as variable.

Comment: It worked!! How could I not have thought of this!!! Now, if I use single quote, the generated command is gcc 'my dir/test.c' -o 'my dir/test.out'. Similarly for double quotes; in my case. Thanks a lot @RuslanOsmanov. You saved my day